# What is the correct way to punctuate the words ‘worse even’?

Tags: punctuation

I’m unsure if this is written as:

‘Worse even, than...’

‘Worse, even, than...’

‘Worse, even than...’

Or without commas at all.

I tried looking it up, but all I can find are examples of the usage of ‘worse still’ and ‘even worse than’.

Comment: _Even_ has been inserted into the phrase _worse than_, so I would put a comma on each side of it.

Comment: @KateBunting If you put that as an answer I would +1

Comment: Choose between "Even worse than" and "Worse than ... even".

Comment: You need to provide complete sentences. For instance, it could be used as an introduction: *Worse even than that, it was too expensive.* (A possibility that you don't mention, but which is quite valid based on the rest of the sentence.) Note that while that's grammatical, it's not the most natural ordering of the words—which is likely (again, based on the rest of the sentence), *even worse than that*.

Comment: Yes, 'even' is a parenthetical here (whereas in 'even worse' it is an intensifier of 'worse', a syntactic difference making little semantic difference). The choices for setting off parentheticals are brackets/parentheses, dashes (both inappropriate in this case), commas (which would work, but appear a little clunky), or in the odd case zero punctuation.  I'd certainly use zero punctuation in this case. // The single-comma suggestions are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Even* has been inserted into the phrase *worse than,* so I would put a comma on each side of it.